# Xfade filter not available with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to concatenate 2 videos using `xfade` filter following [xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) doc leads to `No such filter: 'xfade' ffmpeg error`.

What am I doing wrong?

Context:

- `ffmpeg version 4.2.2`
- `windows 10 something`

Comment: How do you get ffmpeg version '4.2.2'? I get ffmpeg version 'N-93230-gfc32e08941' (crazy!) Is the version maybe what follows, i.e. 'built with gcc 8.2.1'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xfade is brand new and not yet available in latest current `ffmpeg` version (4.2.2).

Download nightly build for windows [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Use 'ffmpeg -filters' to check available filters.

Comment: Thank you for this self answer post! It's encouraging to see this feature in use.

Comment: `xfade` is available since `ffmpeg` version [4.3.0](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/Changelog#L91). No need for nightly build anymore.